# IPHONE: Question about releasing a variable

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Consider this pseudo code:

```
// an image is initialized
UIImage *imagePX = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:... bla bla

imagePX = [self rotateImage:imagePX]; //A
[self doStuff:imagePX]; //B
```

Then I have the rotateImage method:

```
- (UIImage*) rotateImage:(UIImage*)source {
  ... rotate the image... draw on context...
  [source drawInRect... bla bla
  ...

  UIImage *rotatedImage =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  return rotatedImage;
}
```

My question is: imagePX was never released. As the image is passed to the method RotateImage, I thought I could simply release it, after using it on the command [source drawInRect...], as I would return a rotatedImage on the method, but if I do that, the program will crash, because  the variable imagePX should exist so line A can evaluate.

My other problem is that the image will be forwarded on B to another routine. So, what's the best way to make it work without losing track of imagePX and leaking?

What's the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:... bla bla
```

Use

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:...bla bla
```

The latter will be autoreleased.

Comment: of course! I did forget imageWithContentsOfFile! I was considering the one I used and [UIImage imageNamed...] but this last one caches the image using memory that I am trying to save, because I am trying to put my app on a memory diet. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to allocate an instance of UIImage. `imageWithContentsOfFile` is a static method, and can be called on the class itself.

Since `imageWithContentsOfFile` does not include the terms `alloc`, `new`, or `copy` the returned object (by convention) is not retained, and will be autoreleased at the first drain of the autorelease pool.

Conversely, if you ever run into a similar situation where you can't figure out why you are receiving EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors when trying to access this object, it's likely been released too soon. In those cases, you will want to do a manual retain/release within the scope of this class.

Answer (score 0):

What about [UIImage imageNamed:@""]? No alloc, no need to release)